# Stop changing dates automatically in MySQL on tz change

Tags: mysql, timezone

I am using DATETIME field to store my dates in MySQL. Without any timezone specified directly (there is just a datetime column)

But when timezone was changed on server MySQL updated all datetime columns according to new timezone.

Actually switching to EDT was the reason.

I don't need to recalculate my dates automatically - just want to store specific dates in it.

So even if tz changed manually to UTC from EST date should be same (from characters POV) if it was 2016-01-01 18:55 it should be same in any new tz..

I did not run any scripts\queries to update dates.

So it was performed either by MySQL itself or by server.

Need advice what I need to check to find and disable such feature.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using `DATETIME` and not `TIMESTAMP`

[From the MySQL documentation][1]:

> MySQL converts `TIMESTAMP` values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as `DATETIME`.)

You should also review this post (Duplicate):
[Will changing a MySQL timezone change values of DateTime fields in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338480/will-changing-a-mysql-timezone-change-values-of-datetime-fields-in-a-database)

Comment: @Dmitry - Do you have any questions?

Comment: I am sure that affected dates were in datetime fields. I changed tz manually but dates were not changed. So either there is a specific script in system that was ran when system switched to EDT either bug in my code that I cannot find and reproduce.

Comment: System is Ubuntu server not sure which one. One of latest LTE

Comment: ok. Since your manual update to the tz did not change the DateTime field, that establishes the point which MySQL documentation claims. Hence, I would recommend that you take a look at the script which was used to update the system. I doubt it is related to ubuntu. If you are ok with the response please close this so that people can refer to this in future.

Comment: Some more material to support the argument https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for the mess I brought
Just extended my query to grab some old dates - and it looks unchanged

So error defenetly in my code..

Anyway - thanks for your help